# IF else condition on DATE to determine String in other column

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 columns : a DATE column and a STRING column. String column contains 'NEW' and 'OLD' distinct data.

How do I right a conditional query:

```
if DATE is three days old from today
 Then NEW should be 'NO CHANGE'
else
 OLD should be 'CHANGE'
```

meaning if it is not older than 3 days then OLD.

NEW = 'CHANGE', OLD = 'NO CHANGE' like you will use in a CASE statement but how can I account for the date condition to drive the choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i didn't understood what you are meaning with *"NEW = 'CHANGE', OLD = 'NO CHANGE' like you will ..."* so i wrote 2 cases

*Assuming that `DataColumn` and `StrnigColumn` are the columns names and `myTable` is the table name*

you have to use a `CASE` with the `DATEADD` function

```
UPDATE myTable
SET StringColumn = CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY,GETDATE(), -3) > DateColumn 
                        THEN 'NO CHANGE' 
                        ELSE 'CHANGE'
                   END
```

if you mean by *"NEW = 'CHANGE', OLD = 'NO CHANGE' like you will ..."* that you have also to check the value so your query will look like

```
UPDATE myTable
SET StringColumn = CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY,GETDATE(), -3) > DateColumn AND StringColumn ='OLD'
                                            THEN 'NO CHANGE' 
                        WHEN DATEADD(DAY,GETDATE(), -3) <= DateColumn AND StringColumn ='NEW'
                                            THEN 'CHANGE'
                        ELSE [StringColumn]
                   END
```